# Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Tags: java, android

`datasnapshot.getvalue(Event.class)` is not accessing `ArrayList` from `Event.java` please resolve this issue

**Code:**

```
 for (int a= 0; a<idd.size(); a++){
                    if (idd.get(a).equals(userId)){

                        System.out.println("AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBB");
                        Event event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                        System.out.println("AAAAA5555555");
                        list.add(event);
                    }
                }
```

'Here is the java class with ArrayList which is accessing by mainActivity '

**Event.java:**

```
    public class Event {
    private String name, startDate, endDate, mode;
    private ArrayList userID;
    public Event() {
        userID = new ArrayList();
        this.name = new String();
        this.startDate = new String();
        this.endDate = new String();
        this.mode = new String();

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public void setMode(String spinner) {
        this.mode = spinner;
    }

    public ArrayList getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(ArrayList userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}
```

**Here is the Error and app also crashes**

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:224)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
```

Comment: Highly unclear but I'd definitely start by _not_ using raw `List`s (also the `new String()` instantiation idiom is a code smell - if you need a non-`null` default value just use `""`)

Comment: Hi, Instead of ```private ArrayList userID;``` try to use ```private ArrayList<Integer> userID;```  or use Object instead of Integer, or what you have inside the list

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem in my class, using *.toObject(MyClass.class)*

The problem was on my ArrayList of the HashMap that was within the HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList>>
```

The problem was easily fixed by converting the ArrayList to the following (in my case to Integer):

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>
```

**Note that the class I'm using (MyClass.class) to make the ".toObject()" is implementing Serialization**

Answer (score -1):

As was noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286475/class-java-util-arraylist-has-generic-type-parameters-please-use-generictypeind/69296958#comment122463899_69286475):

Instead of `private ArrayList userID;` try to use `private ArrayList<Integer> userID;` or use `Object` instead of `Integer`, or what you have inside the list

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just did what is written in the answer. Actually i changed ArrayList userID to ArrayList<String> userID